# How can I set a default 'chmod' in a Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems, chmod

A previous question just to understand what I'm doing: *[How to change permissions for a folder and its subfolders/files in one step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152)*

So if I change the `chmod to 755` for `chmod 75 /opt/lampp/htdocs` and I restart the system I want the files to be in `chmod 755`.

Comment: you really shouldn't post duplicate questions.

Comment: Sorry, I think the two questions are very related to each other and I didn't wanted to add a new question for my last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once set, Linux filesystem permissions are unaffected by rebooting the system, unless you have some non-standard software running at boot time which is going back to change them to some default.

Comment: Hmm I'm on Windows 7 with `VirtualBox` because currently I'm testing something, do you think it's because of `VirtualBox` and If I will use a real Linux will save the changed chmod?

Comment: a) I'm positive that file permissions are persistent on a standard linux install b) are you sure you're not starting from a snapshot of your virtualbox instance where the permissions are not set? Try taking a new image of your machine after they're set how you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx PathOfFolder
```

Answer (score 0):

If some process is changing them at boot, place a changeback in /etc/rc.local.

Comment: err... shouldn't we ideally track the offending process instead of ignoring the problem?

Comment: I gave up tracking the automation system in ubuntu long ago. I'm convinced the developers do not understand Unix anymore.