# Can I set permissions when creating a file or directory?

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions, file-permissions, chmod

Can I set permissions when I create a file/directory using a single command  or do I have to create the file/directory first and then use chmod to set its permissions?

For instance to do something like this

```
// for directories
mkdir 755 test 

// for files
touch 644 test/my_file.php
```

Comment: Take a look at this command: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?install

and more specifically the -d and -m flags.

Comment: You can use && to write all these commands in one line.

Comment: @Anton Glukhov you mean like this? :  mkdir test && 755 or  touch test/my_file.php &&  644

Comment: touch filename && chmod 755 filename

Comment: Look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600319/bash-run-one-command-after-another-even-if-i-suspend-the-first-one-ctrl-z There are &&, ||, etc.

Comment: For directories: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786326/how-to-create-a-directory-and-give-permission-in-single-command

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For files, try using `install` command:

```
$ install -m 644 /test/path/ myfile.php
```

For folders, `mkdir` with `-m` param:

```
$ mkdir -m 755 test
```

You might have to execute that as `sudo`.

Answer (score 3):

Man pages are your friend. This is possible with GNU mkdir but not with GNU touch.

```
mkdir -m 755 test
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following command to create directory and give permissions at the same time

```
mkdir -m755 test
```