# Magento theme not working

Tags: php, xml, magento, helper, magento-1.9

I have purchased a theme from themeforest and I downloaded the zip file. Then I extracted it according to the documentation along with the zip file. Then I added *"app, js, media, skin to the correspondent folders"*.

Compilation mode is disabled (default). Then I went to admin panel and cleared cache, but when I opened my frontend it shows me an error saying:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Jollyanytheme_Helper_Data' not found in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\Mage.php on line 547

I have googled it and referred several questions such as:

- [Magento Helper Class Not Found Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242292/magento-helper-class-not-found-error)
- [Magento : Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Giftcards_Helper_Data' not found in ...../app/Mage.php on line 546](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590164/magento-fatal-error-class-mage-giftcards-helper-data-not-found-in-app)

But I could not reveal any useful information from those questions.

How can I sort this out?

Comment: This problem has been introduced by following the installation instructions of the theme-vendor. From your question it's not clear whether the error was introduced personally by yourself or is already within the installation instructions. You solve such problems by contacting the vendor of the software you've got a problem with and ask for support describing your problem. These kind of problems are normally easy to fix however are less a programming question fitting for stackoverflow as it highly depends on the software in question (which is not part of your question).

Comment: From http://themeforest.net/item/jollyany-corporate-multi-purpose-magento-theme/8469671 : *"Need support? Submit to Our Ticket or Send email to us"* <- you should do that instead of asking here. See as well: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Do you really think that I didn't submit a ticket? As I told, I didn't have much time. So I went all possible way that I can, so here also. and I got support today. Guess what, fixed.

Comment: I couldn't see from your question that you opened a support ticket (you didn't wrote about it) so I *commented* just in case you didn't think about it so far. As you already did, all should be fine. Especially as you'Ve got a solution now, please add the answer you get from the support below and explain what the problem was and how you fixed it.

Comment: I needed to add two file directories that were in different folders. Means in first step I need to install app,js,media,skin etc, and in second step I need to install etc modules.

Comment: If you explain that in an answer below you would complete your question here. This is accepted practice (answering your own questions) and welcomed. If you even then accept it it will mark your question as answered. Let me know if you run into any problems with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it, I needed to add two file directories that were in different folders. Means in first step I need to install app,js,media,skin etc, and in second step I need to install etc modules also. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Check that in your app/code/local/Jollyanytheme/Helper/Data.php is exists with following code

```
class Mage_Jollyanytheme_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

If not then add it.