# Server Apache - Change only file but not folder (and vice versa)

Tags: apache, chmod

With this command I can set all file and folder in "img" to 0775:

```
chmod 775 -R /var/www/site.com/img/
```

But would I like change only the file inside the folder img; how can I do? 
And for change only the folders?

Thanks

Comment: I find the solution [here][1].

Thanks


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubunt/11512211#11512211

Answer (score 2):

ok,

To recursively change dirs or files rights

```
find /root/path -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 755 
find /root/path -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644
```

Comment: Thank; inside of folder "img" there are more others folder; I would like to change only the folders (files set to 644 and folder set to 755) can you help me?