# find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ;

Tags: find, chmod

why doesn't this work I am trying to change all files to 644 abd all -d to 755:

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ;
```

**i get: find: missing argument to `-exec'**
 thanks

Comment: Terminate with `\;` not with `;` alone.

Comment: ...that's because everything following `-exec` is treated as its argument.  If you had a bare `;` it would be treated as a terminator for the entire `find`, but really you need to terminate the `exec`, so it must be escaped as a part of the argument string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set chmod for a folder and all of its subfolders and files in Linux Ubuntu Terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubunt)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thank You!!!!

Answer (score 184):

Piping to xargs is a dirty way of doing that which can be done inside of find.

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
```

You can be even more controlling with other options, such as:

```
find . -type d -user harry -exec chown daisy {} \;
```

You can do some very cool things with find and you can do some very dangerous things too.  Have a look at "man find", it's long but is worth a quick read.  And, as always remember:

- If you are root it will succeed.
- If you are in root (/) you are going to have a bad day.
- Using /path/to/directory can make things a lot safer as you are clearly defining where you want find to run.

Comment: Why would the xargs method be a "dirty way"? It has the huge advantage of running chmod only once, with all files as arguments. The "-exec chmod" method will create a subprocess per file.

Comment: If you want to only run chmod once, then change it to `find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} +` which works essentially the same as the xargs method, building one command line. (The \ above is only to escape the semicolon.)

Comment: Quick oneliner: `find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;`

Comment: Note - xargs is generally superior to exec. With exec, the command is invoked for EACH input but with xargs the command is usually just run ONCE. So if your find query gives thousands of results, xargs will be several folds faster !

Answer (score 23):

A good alternative is this:

```
find . -type f | xargs chmod -v 644
```

and for directories:

```
find . -type d | xargs chmod -v 755
```

and to be more explicit:

```
find . -type f | xargs -I{} chmod -v 644 {}
```

Comment: How to handle found files that has spaces? I am getting errors, the name of the file is splitted by spaces and it tries to run chmod for each splitted part.

Comment: @Lidia, try using adding `-print0` option to find and `xargs -0`.

Comment: @TAllieri Thanks a lot

Answer (score 15):

I need this so often that I created a function in my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
chmodf() {
        find $2 -type f -exec chmod $1 {} \;
}
chmodd() {
        find $2 -type d -exec chmod $1 {} \;
}
```

Now I can use these shortcuts:

```
chmodd 0775 .
chmodf 0664 .
```