# Vagrant file_put_contents permission denied

Tags: php, vagrant

I cannot seem to allow permissions in vagrant. I am attempting to run importbuddy.php in order to migrate a WordPress instance. I get the following error.

`file_put_contents(/path/): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

I have setup permissions to 777 on the `www` directory, but that changes nothing. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

While recursively setting folder and file permissions to 777 should fix your problem (instructions for doing so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubunt)), the root of this is probably an issue with the ownership of the files and folders.

The owner of shared folders is usually 'vagrant' but the server itself (if you're using Ubuntu) runs as user and group 'www-data'. You can view the user/group of your files by sshing into your VM (`vagrant ssh`), navigating to the directory in question and entering `ls -l` in your console.

If you're running apache, then you can update the user to 'vagrant' by editing the following file (`/etc/apache2/envvars`) like below:

Find this section

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

And change it to

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=vagrant
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=vagrant
```

Afterward just be sure to restart apache (with this command `sudo service apache2 restart`) and the file permission errors should be fixed