# Yii2 unable to write to assets folder

Tags: php, vagrant, yii2

I have just installed a fresh copy of Yii2 advanced and am having trouble getting the style sheets to load. The error seems to be that Yii (or webserver) cannot create path `/var/www/frontend/web/assets/1ecfb338/css` despite doing so in the same http request that it errors. Even after reinforcing file permissions of 777 from without and outside the VM, Yii doesn't seem to make further attempts to write the stylesheet.

[image]

If I just refresh the page loads without error but the stylesheet bootstrap.css has not been created in the directory.

This is most frustrating. Does anyone have any ideas?

If it matters I am running Yii in a Vagrant VM with Virtualbox. Debian is the VM OS and Ubuntu is the host.

Comment: Provide write permissions to the assets folder.

Comment: you just apply this permission using terminal `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/frontend/web/assets`

Comment: Hey Dubby : If @vishu answer helped you. Then, please tick it as correct anwer. As, it will help other user to find it easily. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite strange at not experienced this before. I was able to correct this by changing the mode to 777 **as the super user** from **outside** the virtual machine. From doing the same thing inside the virtual machine made no difference.

I have worked on many projects before with this kind of setup but not had this before. Software that I'm using that may be responsible is:

**Host machine:**

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Vagrant 1.7.4
- Virtualbox 4.3.30

**Virtual machine:**

- Debian Jessie
- Nginx 1.6.2
- PHP 5.6.14

Edit: I found that I had defined the sync folder incorrectly. I had to change to rule this this:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www", id: "vagrant-root", :group=>'www-data', :mount_options=>['dmode=775,fmode=775']
```

Comment: This answer explains perfectly what's going on and how to fix it. But to be more specific it would be better to let fmode in 664.  
You can find more info here 
http://jeremykendall.net/2013/08/09/vagrant-synced-folders-permissions/.  
But, to sum up,
this is the line that fix the issue  

`config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www", id: "vagrant-root", :group=>'www-data', :mount_options=>['dmode=775,fmode=664']`

Answer (score 1):

You just give permission for particular directory like:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/frontend/web/assets
```

Comment: or `sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/frontend/web/assets` to just change the group (slightly more secure).

Comment: I guess that I'm not explaining this well. The permissions are correct and Yii is creating the directory, but still errors. Maybe the error is occurring because it's trying to create the directory when it already exists (because it just created it). I think I'm going to have to look at the Yii source to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was adding

> sed -i  's/www-data/vagrant/g' /etc/apache2/envvars

to the Vagrantfile like written here
[Vagrant file_put_contents permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854013/vagrant-file-put-contents-permission-denied)