# npm install showing some error EACCESS

Tags: node.js, npm

```
    i recently reinstalled ubuntu os and installed npm and nodejs, but when i run npm install i am issues with EACCESS which i am unable to understand, anyhelp ?
i was googling it about this issue but still could not fix it from hours, even i was going through many posts in stackoverflow but none solved my issue, can anyone please let me y is it happening ?

     npm install

    > angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall /home/sri/oxkey
    > bower install

    /home/sri/oxkey/node_modules/bower/node_modules/configstore/index.js:56
                    throw err;
                    ^

    Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/sri/.config/configstore/bower-github.yml'
    You don't have access to this file.

        at Error (native)
        at Object.fs.openSync (evalmachine.<anonymous>:549:18)
        at Object.fs.readFileSync (evalmachine.<anonymous>:397:15)
        at Object.create.all.get (/home/sri/oxkey/node_modules/bower/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:29)
        at Object.Configstore (/home/sri/oxkey/node_modules/bower/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
        at readCachedConfig (/home/sri/oxkey/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:19:23)
        at defaultConfig (/home/sri/oxkey/node_modules/bower/lib/config.js:11:12)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sri/oxkey/node_modules/bower/lib/index.js:16:32)
        at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)

    npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-22-generic
    npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
    npm ERR! node v4.2.4
    npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall: `bower install`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall script 'bower install'.
    npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-seed package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     bower install
    npm ERR! You can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-seed
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /home/sri/oxkey/npm-debug.log
```

***heres my package.json file*** 
may be there might be some silly mistakes, but really i am not able to get out of this.may i know why we will be getting this kind of errors actually ? Any help would be appreciated

```
{
  "name": "angular-seed",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "A starter project for AngularJS",
  "repository": "https://github.com/angular/angular-seed",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.1",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "http-server": "^0.6.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "karma": "~0.12",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.12",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.5",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^2.1.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.2.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",
    "prestart": "npm install",

    "start": "lr-http-server",
    "pretest": "npm install",
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
    "test-single-run": "karma start karma.conf.js  --single-run",
    "preupdate-webdriver": "npm install",
    "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
    "preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver",
    "protractor": "protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js",
    "update-index-async": "node -e \"require('shelljs/global'); sed('-i', /\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_START@@[\\s\\S]*\\/\\/@@NG_LOADER_END@@/, '//@@NG_LOADER_START@@\\n' + sed(/sourceMappingURL=angular-loader.min.js.map/,'sourceMappingURL=bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js.map','app/bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js') + '\\n//@@NG_LOADER_END@@', 'app/index-async.html');\""
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you really have to change the permissions to those files.

Comment: can u explain me how to do that please!

Comment: You have to use `chmod -R <permissions> <folder>`. Tale a look at [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubunt) and Its answers.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your npm cache:

`npm cache clean`

and run following command to grant access to specified directory

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.config`

After that you need to install it again from scratch and everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

If just *sudo*-ing still fails with EACCESS, try:

```
sudo npm c get user
```

By doing this, I found out that when *sudo*-ed, the **npm** was using my orignal user ID (!) Using temporary configuration override `user = 0` might be the easiest fix in this case. Beware not to use it for local installations, though!

This behavior of **npm** occurred to me after some system update (using Mac OS 10.13.6), but I'm unable to figure out, when exactly it happened.

Answer (score -3):

You have to be root. Try:

```
sudo npm install
```

and then type your root password

Comment: i tried it earlier only, but even then its not working

Comment: Can you give us your package.json in opening post?

Comment: This way it expose security risks