# reveal.js: How to edit and save?

Tags: bash, reveal.js

I'm trying reveal.js for the first time and just cloned and installed the [full setup](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#full-setup). I opened the slide presentation on the local host and played around for few seconds. So far so good. Afterwards I closed the presentation and went for editing the index.html file but when I tried to save I got the message I didn't have the permission to edit. Then I checked:

```
[reveal.js (master)]$ ls -lg ~/.../reveal.js/index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 1479 mag  5 10:15 ~/.../reveal.js/index.html
```

So I went for changing the permissions using find as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubunt). That gives:

```
[reveal.js (master)]$ sudo find ~/.../reveal.js -type f -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Checked again:

```
[reveal.js (master)]$ ls -lg ~/.../reveal.js/index.html
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root 1479 mag  5 10:15 ~/.../reveal.js/index.html
```

Thought everything was fine but when I tried to edit again and still I don't have the permissions.

Anyone has a clue on that?

**Edit:** tried also the recursive version of the find command

```
[reveal.js (master)]$ sudo find ~/.../reveal.js -type f -exec chmod 755 -R {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the simplest command as possible:

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw
```

Shame.

Comment: You just gave **everyone** on the system write access to your files and directories. That's a **horrible** idea.

Comment: Why? This is my personal computer. Do I have any reason to worry about that I can't see?

Comment: Because it is bad practice and you shouldn't do it and because even on a single-user machine there are processes running under different accounts for a reason. You don't want to expose things to rogue processes that don't need to see/edit things. It also just isn't a valid solution to **anything**.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the insight. Could you please give me a suggestion to solve the problem differently?

Comment: What does `ls -l` on the file(s) output? What user are you trying this as? Running `sudo chmod -R o-w` would be a **tremendous** improvement by itself.