# Setting up DVWA : this page is not working

Tags: xampp, localhost

I put a downloaded file from DVWA in /opt/lampp/htdocs
and change config.inc.php.dist to config.inc.php
but when I open localhost/DVWA this is what shows up:

> This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this
> request. HTTP ERROR 500

Answer (score 1):

From [the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.1):

> The 500 (Internal Server Error) status code indicates that the server
> encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling
> the request.

Since this is the only piece of information you are delivering, some *suggestions* may be :

1. Check what the error log file says. You can find it in this location `/opt/lampp/logs/error_log` . You will find more information about the problem there
2. Check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216761/the-localhost-page-isn-t-working-localhost-is-currently-unable-to-handle-this-re) question, I think that your problem is similar to that one, checking it may help you.