# Don't getting Permission to access a php file on apache2

Tags: server, apache2, lampp

I was trying to test an php application on my apache2 server. I am using LAMPP stack.

I have given the path address in following format-

> http://localhost/folder/file.php

And got following result-

> You don't have permission to access /folder/file.php on this server.

Comment: are you using any framework?

Comment: No, just raw php. but for design I am using bootstrap.

Comment: Try to set necessary permissions for the folder you want to access

Comment: Can please tell me, how to set permissions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubunt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the detailed answer for this question you may read the following question and its answers

[How do I set chmod for a folder and all of its subfolders and files in Linux Ubuntu Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubunt)