# Linux directory and file permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

Lets say I have directory `/a` with permissions `wx` and file `/a/b` with permission `x`. What can I do with file b? Can I read it, write or i cannot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set chmod for a folder and all of its subfolders and files in Linux Ubuntu Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-do-i-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubu)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

You can read it but can't write to it and off course you can execute it.

Comment: I tried to simulate this situation and found out, that I cannot read simple .txt file (for example with cat).

Answer (score 0):

You can write inside the dir /a but can't see what are inside the dir. 
You can create file or new dir inside /a.
If you know the name of the file inside the dir, you can execute it only if it has also read permission, so you cannot execute the file /a/b.