# All my ipython notebooks are suddenly read only. Running Ubuntu with windows dual boot

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter

I have a windows and ubuntu dual boot system.

I experimented a little and this only happens to my notebooks which are in a /media directory. I have been working with jupyter notebooks in my /media directory with no problems before today.

[image: Screenshot of a jupyter notebook]

When I try to create a new Python 2 notebook, I get this error:

```
An error occurred while creating a new notebook.


Unexpected error while saving file: Untitled Folder/Untitled.ipynb [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/media/james/OS/cygwin64/home/colleen/Untitled Folder/Untitled.ipynb'
```

How do I make it not read-only and everything back to normal?

Answer (score 1):

First try changing the mount options to enable your user have to write access:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1 /media
```

(Replace `/dev/sda1` with the correct partition for `media`.)

You can also put it in `/etc/fstab`.

Then, if needed, check if your user has write permissions for `/media`. If you don't, you can add it by doing:

```
chmod 644 /media
```

And to set all [files 644 and folders to 755, see this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11512211/1431750):

> To change all the directories to 755 (`drwxr-xr-x`):
>
> ```
> find /opt/lampp/htdocs -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
> ```
>
> To change all the files to 644 (`-rw-r--r--`):
>
> ```
> find /opt/lampp/htdocs -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
> ```

Comment: Ah, I solved it. I forgot to use `shutdown /s /t 0` in Windows. Silly me