# Sybase IQ Load Table using client file is failing

Tags: load, sybase, sap-iq

I am using Sybase IQ 15 version database.

trying to load IQ table from delimited flat file

```
Load Table test (a,b)
using client file '/xyz/test.dat'
ESCAPES OFF
FORMAT BCP
DELIMITED BY '|';
```

is it failing with below error

```
Msg 21, Level 14, State 0:SQL Anywhere Error -1006140: I/O Error on file/xyz/test.dat - (hos_clientfileio.cxx 142)
```

set below option on IQ server level ,still getting same error

```
set option allow_read_client_file='on' ;
grant READCLIENTFILE to finsrv ;
```

data file is on unix client machine and File content as below

> 1|01
>
> 2|02

Can someone please help/advice?

Comment: NOTE: I'm assuming `/xyz/` is an attempt to mask your actual directory structure.] Have you verified that you've provided the correct (full) path to the file?  At the OS level command prompt, does `ls /xyz/test.dat` show your file or generate an error?

Comment: Yes, /xyx/ is masked value and ls command lists correct file without error

Answer (score 0):

Its likely a userright permission settings issue.

Try to change all the directories of /xyz/test.dat to 755 (drwxr-xr-x):

shell command at client machine:

1 - `sudo chmod 755 -R /xyz/`

or

2 - `find /xyz/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11512211/8928024) on SO for more detail on user-rights and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) for official Ubuntu explanation.