# Laravel 5: Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: linux, laravel, permissions, storage

I have my project in local development and all it's working fine.

When I pass the project to a rasberry and try to make it works I'm getting some errors I try to find the solution in other questions like this here in stackoverflow but it not works.

When I call to a function who it's working with storage folder I get this error:

With `sudo chmod -R 775 storage/`

```
The stream or file "/var/www/html/test/storage/logs/laravel.log" could 
not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

And if I change the permission to 777 I get this error:

```
file_put_contents(/var/www/html/test/resources/views/projects/problema.blade.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

How should be the permission of the folder to make it works?

Comment: do you set the owner with `chown`  to `www-data` or whatever your web user called?

Comment: Of which folder? I think give permission 777 it's not a good idea, but anyway, if I give 777 to storage folder i should make `chown -R www-data:www-data storage`? or to resource folder? @devnullΨ

Comment: set `www-data` to your project, also set permissions `755` for files  and `644` for folders, read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-do-i-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubu

Comment: also read https://superuser.com/questions/646062/granting-write-permissions-to-www-data-group

Comment: Ok I think I get it @devnullΨ can you start a chat room please?

Comment: I don't know how to start the chat, I think it does it automatically

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163402/laravel-5-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied

Comment: Go to chat stackoverflow and find the room with this name: Laravel 5 permission folder @devnullΨ

Answer (score 0):

This is what i used to do for the linux installations :

```
sudo usermod -a -G apache your_user
sudo chown -R your_user:apache /var/www
sudo chmod 2775 /var/www
find /var/www -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} \;
find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} \;
```

You should be fine with these permissions.You can replace the group and user and you need. Never provide a 777 permission to any of the folders.

Comment: Ok, let me ask you first something. I'm on a rasberry with some users. If I write `whoami` I get my user Lluis. Also in /var/www I have more folders that aren't mine. My folder location is: /var/www/html/test.

So my commands will be this?
1 - `sudo usermod -a -G apache lluis` 2 - `sudo chown -R lluis:apache /var/www/html/test` 3 - `sudo chmod 2775 /var/www/html/test` 4 - `find /var/www/html/test -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} \;` and finally 5 - `find /var/www/html/test -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} \;`

Comment: I wan't to be sure I don't touch anything isn't mine @Shan

Comment: can you check what is the permission given to /var/www folder ?

Comment: Yes @Shan drwxr-xr-x to www folder

Comment: Ok, so you have 755 for www, and confirm the owner/group info also

Comment: I have also 755 on /html and on /test, the owner/group of info is root @Shan

Comment: So, "The owner has read, write and execute permissions; the group and others can only read and execute". Im not sure that you still have the write permission because your user/group seems root/root respectively. try those commands that you mentioned in your first command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163407/discussion-between-lluis-puig-ferrer-and-shan).