# Permission issues with external ntfs HDD, gitlab-ctl reconfigure changing permissions: "Operation not permitted"

Tags: unix, gitlab, chmod, gitlab-omnibus

I'm using gitlab on a rasberry pi model 3 B. Following some **information** about my **setup** (`sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:env:info`):

```
System information
System:         Raspbian 8.0
Current User:   git
Using RVM:      no
Ruby Version:   2.3.6p384
Gem Version:    2.6.13
Bundler Version:1.13.7
Rake Version:   12.3.0
Redis Version:  3.2.11
Git Version:    2.14.3
Sidekiq Version:5.0.5
Go Version:     go1.3.3 linux/arm

GitLab information
Version:        10.6.0-rc3
Revision:       52fa89e
Directory:      /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails
DB Adapter:     postgresql
URL:            http://gitlab.example.com
HTTP Clone URL: http://gitlab.example.com/some-group/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@gitlab.example.com:some-group/some-project.git
Using LDAP:     no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:        6.0.3
Repository storage paths:
- default:      /mnt/SeagateExpansion/GitLab/repositories
Hooks:          /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks
Git:            /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git
```

After the gitlab update to version 10.6.0 I need to change the url again but when I do the necessary changes in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and run `sudo nano gitlab-ctl reconfigure` I get the following **error messages**:

```
  ========================================================================
  Error executing action `run` on resource 'ruby_block[directory resource: 
  /mnt/SeagateExpansion/GitLab]'
  ========================================================================
```

and

```
============================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 
'storage_directory[/mnt/SeagateExpansion/GitLab]'
============================================================================
```

The **result message** says:

```
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

storage_directory[/mnt/SeagateExpansion/GitLab] (gitlab::gitlab-rails line 42) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: ruby_block[directory resource: /mnt/SeagateExpansion/GitLab] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/package/resources/storage_directory.rb line 33) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of chmod 00700 /mnt/SeagateExpansion/GitLab ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: chmod: changing permissions of ‘/mnt/SeagateExpansion/GitLab’: Operation not permitted
---- End output of chmod 00700 /mnt/SeagateExpansion/GitLab ----
Ran chmod 00700 /mnt/SeagateExpansion/GitLab returned 1
```

---

So the problem seems to be, that the execution of the *run* and *create* command on the resource storage (*GitLab* folder on the external HDD [HDD = SeagateExpansion]) **expects the permissions to be 700, right?**
According to this errors I tried to change the permission of 
 the external HDD folder `/mnt/SeagateExpansion/GitLab` see the `ls -l` output:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 root GitLabUser        0 Jan  4 17:55 GitLab
```

With the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-do-i-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubu) post I tried to change the permission with the command:

```
sudo find /mnt/SeagateExpansion/GitLab -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
```

to the required **permission 700**. But the changes don't take affect. I also tried `chmod -R 700 /mnt/SeagateExpansion/GitLab` and executed the commands as *root* but the changes don't take effect. Even after restarting the raspberry pi. What am I doing wrong?

I also tried to change the *options* settings/flag of the HDD in `/etc/fstab` to `user` but this doesn't help ether.

I'm thankful for every hint and answer :).

Best regards,

Bredjo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The solution is to change the mount settings in the `/etc/fstab`. Because if you have the wrong options settings (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab) you are not able to change the permissions because its a `ntfs` filesystem.

So my **old** `fstab` entry was this:

```
UUID=FE820568820526AD   /mnt/SeagateExpansion   ntfs defaults,gid=GitLabUser   0       0
```

And the **new** entry is this:

```
 UUID=FE820568820526AD   /mnt/SeagateExpansion   ntfs-3g permissions   0       0
```

Note that you need to install *ntfs-3g* to use it in `fstab`. And the `permissions` options only comes with *ntfs-3g*. See: https://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/ownership-and-permissions/

After this change I executed again:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

Now the error disappeared and the permission **700** of the folder `/mnt/SeagateExpansion/GitLab` could be set. I also noticed that the owner of the `GitLab` folder was also changed to user `git` after the reconfiguration:

```
drwx------ 1 git  root        0 Jan  4 17:55 GitLab
```

That's because I don't need the option `gid=GitLabUser`any more. 

Now everything works again :).