# chown -R exclude some directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, chmod, chown

I want to exclude some large content directory

I'm Using it to chown Directory

```
chown -R admin /home/admin/web/public_html
```

is there anyway to exclude a subdirectory under html

Like:

```
chown -R admin exclude=/home/admin/web/public_html/content /home/admin/web/public_html
```

Something like that

Thanks

Comment: chown does not do that.  Only solution I see if to use the find command to get a list, `grep -v` what you want to exclude, then run the chown in a loop on the list of files.

Comment: Thanks @Nic3500 Please show me the command code. because I had try a find

Comment: Look up `find -type f` options, `while`, `grep -v`

Comment: I try that: `find . -type d \( -path contents -o -path admin/logs -o -path admin/data/backup -o -path admin/data/conversion -o -path admin/smarty/cache -o -path admin/data/engine/storage -o -path 78 -o -path 976 -o -path tmp \) -prune -o -print | xargs chown -R admin`

Comment: Can you please give me an example command

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I hope this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-do-i-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubu

Answer (score 1):

You can to use a script with a loop, similar to this:

```
path_list=$(find /home/admin/web/public_html)

for path in $path_list
do
   if test $path != "/home/admin/web/public_html/content"
   then
       chown -R admin $path
   fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks.. Lets test it. @almuhs