# How to Delete Data From Mysql also files From Folder in php

Tags: php

```
 <?php

 if (isset($_GET['delete']))
 {
include("config.php");

 $empid = $_GET['empid'];
 $query1= mysql_query("select * from faculty where empid='$empid'");
 $row1=mysql_fetch_array($query1);
 $image=$row["image_name"];
 unlink("../images/photos_faculty/".$image);


$sql = "DELETE FROM faculty WHERE empid = '" . $_GET["empid"] . "'";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

if($result)
{
    echo 'Data Deleted';
}else{
    echo 'Data Not Deleted';
}
mysql_close($conn);
}

 ?>
```

How to  Delete Data From Mysql  also files From Folder in php
using above code i am getting

Anyone please solve this...how to get permission for deleting the image

```
error unlink(../images/photos_faculty/): Permission denied
```

Comment: Change your folder permission read, wright and exicute...

Comment: See `../images/photos_faculty/`? There's __no file__ after `/`. So `$image` is empty?

Comment: how to check permission

Comment: FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which one is best for you.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: nlink("../images/photos_faculty/".$image);

Comment: Where you are using in your local or server. If server means which server

Comment: If you're on Mac/Linux, do `chmod -R 777 images` (where `images` is your `images` folder). If that fixes the problem, change the `777` to something a bit more strict.

Comment: can anyone write the permission code where should i place.

Comment: we are not talking about code...do some stuffs in google... before ask here...:(

Comment: using local server

Comment: windows or linux?

Comment: linux server....

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-do-i-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubu