# IntelliJ "Run tests with coverage" is always at 0% and shows an AccessDeniedException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-coverage

I'm running the elasticsearch gradle project in my IDE.

I'm able to execute tests & debug.
But I'm failing to see any coverage reports.

 `"AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "~/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2018.1/coverage/coverage-error.log" "write")`

I've attached a screenshot of my IDE.[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are mission is that when you run `chmod 777` on directory, **it only changes the permission of that directory only**. You also need to change the permissions of the files and directories which are inside of that directory.

For this run the following command to change the permissions **recursively for all files and directories**:

```
chmod -R <permissionsettings> <dirname>
```

Or just change the permission of that particular file to avoid setting permission `777` to all the files.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-do-i-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files) for more information about permissions in linux: