# Setting multiple file permissions at once using ssh ( recursive folder/file permission )

Tags: linux, wordpress, ssh

I am working with digital ocean and WordPress. I have uploaded my theme and my file permissions are all wrong. I know how to set the file permissions individually using ssh but I'm wondering if I can do multiple at once rather than doing each individually. I want to set all folders inside my theme to `755` and all files to `644` (correct me if this is wrong)

Here's what I have done so far; I navigated to my theme folder using ssh then used to following command to set file permissions;

```
chmod 644 file.php
chmod 755 folder
```

Comment: Duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-change-permissions-for-a-folder-and-its-subfolders-files-in-one-step

Answer (score 1):

`chmod -R 755` will set these permissions to all files and subfolders in the tree. To set the directories to 755 and either leave the files alone or set them to 644. For this, you can use the find command. For example:

To change all the directories to 755 (drwxr-xr-x):

```
find /opt/lampp/htdocs -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

To change all the files to 644 (-rw-r--r--):

```
find /opt/lampp/htdocs -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try below command for directory

find /var/www/html/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

Below command is for files permission

find /var/www/html/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;