# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' api.js:1 in webGL

Tags: javascript, webgl, webgl-globe, webgl-earth

I'm trying to intwegrate WebGL Link: https://sites.google.com/site/webglearth/

but when i run the same in browser i'm getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
> api.js:1
>
> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: WE is not defined
>     at initialize (index-new.html:7)
> ```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="http://www.webglearth.com/v2/api.js"></script>
        <script>
          function initialize() {
              var options = {
              sky: true,
              atmosphere: true,
              zooming: true
          };
            var earth = new WE.map('earth_div',options);
            WE.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{
             
            }).addTo(earth);
          }
        </script>
        <style>
          html, body{padding: 0; margin: 0;}
          #earth_div{top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; position: absolute !important;}
        </style>
        <title>WebGL Earth API: Hello World</title>
      </head>
      <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="earth_div"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Aby solution to solve this issue is highly appreciated

Comment: I ran your code and everything was OK. Also I updated your question to create snippet and it's working correctly

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi: But on some system it is showing this error

Comment: Can you run it via proxy or vpn?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi: Yes but same issue, on some system it is working without vpn but getting error on other system

Comment: Ok I think you need to download the script from CDN link and reference it locally

Comment: i'm getting this warning also `https://webglearth.com/v2/api.js was loaded even though its MIME type ("text/html")` is this can be the issue?

Comment: See this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55353671/why-do-i-get-a-df-worker-min-js-was-loaded-even-though-its-mime-type-text-ht

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236256/discussion-between-user3653474-and-alireza-ahmadi).