# Blazor Server Side MIME type error for content JS file

Tags: javascript, mime-types, blazor-server-side

I've create a base assembly `BaseDll` that compiles as a referenced project by my main Blazor Server Side `MainBSSApp`.

The base assembly contains a few JS functions that are located in the `myJSFile.js` file of the `BaseDll` assembly (I've added them into a `BaseDll.wwwroot` folder).

So I add the reference to my JS file in `MainBSSApp/Shared/_Host.cshtml` (I actually tried several places, result is always the same - I now have it in the `<head>` section):

```
<script src="_content/BaseDll/myJSFile.js"></script>
```

When I execute the `MainBSSApp` on my standard VS version (Windows) all seems to work fine. Now I'm trying to migrate the project on `Ubuntu` with VS Code. Views referenced by `BaseDll` as well as services are working fine.
However, as soon as I call any JS method defined in the `myJSFile.js`, I do get an error because the function is not defined - and righ before that, I get the warning that `The scritp from "[...]/_content/BaseDll/myJSFile.js" was loaded even though its MIME type ("text/html") is not a valid JavaScript MIME type."

So I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55766166/2490877) fix but without luck (I tried both 777 and 705 permission, nothing changed)...

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's possible that the MIME error is caused by a middleware error page.... that is caused by the file not being there, or the path being wrong... so a 404 triggers the asp.net error page, which is HTML type.  (Try to load the file by using the browser's location bar... that should confirm....)  Maybe try with this path?:  "~/_content/BaseDll/myJSFile.js" or "./_content/BaseDll/myJSFile.js"

Comment: @pcalkins indeed when I change the filename, it still says it IS found with wrong MIME type although the file does NOT exist. I thus tried your two suggestions and in both cases I get the same error. My assumption is that the file might not be added to the dll - it is not clear how I should make it a "content file" via VS Code - in VS it is listed as "Build Action : Content" - "Do Not Copy" but I cannot find ANY reference of the file name in the base project (i.e. *.sln or *.csproj files) - maybe this is the cause? Any idea about fixing it?

Comment: not familiar with blazor stuff... I think you can bundle it inside the webassembly, though.  That might get around the path issue.

Comment: yep - that's the point - if I add the file to the `MainBSSApp\wwwroot` it works as files from wwwroot are copied automatically... But somehow it doesnt work when adding it from the base assembly...!

Answer (score 1):

Solution is indeed to add the `./` before the `_content`

```
<script src="./_content/BaseDll/myJSFile.js"></script>
```

credits to @pcalkins and to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#location-of-javascipt)...