# Python Acces Denied Download a file with Python in a specifid Path

Tags: python, python-requests

Hello i tried to download something with Python, but when i try to open the script it comes following error code:

```
  File "C:\Users\Colin\Desktop\Fortnite VoidlessFN\Paid\main.py", line 134, in <module>
    open("C:/Users/Colin/Pictures", "wb").write(r.content)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/Colin/Pictures'

MY CODE:
  url144 = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/815696193354203157/817144742693437490/msgbox.vbs"
  r = requests.get(url144, allow_redirects=True)
  open("C:/Users/Colin/Pictures", "wb").write(r.content)
```

Comment: Use `chmod` to change the directory permissions and then run the program

Comment: how to use chmod?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-change-permissions-for-a-folder-and-its-subfolders-files-in-one-step

Comment: @bigbounty His file path is likely he is using Windows rather than Linux

Answer (score 0):

Right.  Because `C:\Users\Colin\Pictures` is a directory.  You can't open a directory for writing.  You need to add a file name to this.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check the permissions on this folder to ensure your python script has write access

---

Comment: This should be a comment