# Erro Flutter VsCode terminal

Tags: flutter

my flutter is giving this error, I can't start android studio, from the VsCode terminal.

This error: The Flutter SDK is installed in a protected folder and may not function correctly. Please move the SDK to a location that is user-writable without Administration permissions and restart.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLaJS.png)

Comment: Have you tried to make the possible solution? Move the folder to another path?
If you don`t wanna change your path try to use this command "chmod -R 755 folder_name"
Based on this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-change-permissions-for-a-folder-and-its-subfolders-files-in-one-step

Comment: i dont know  move the folder ,can you help  me?